# How to navigate in React-Native?

Tags: react-router, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) library in my react-native project and since 6 hours I am trying to navigate from one screen to others screen and have tried every possible way but I think I am not able to get the logic properly.
This is my project structure.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFQFS.png)

The way I am doing it.

```
const AppStack = StackNavigator({ Main: Feeds });
const AuthStack = StackNavigator({ Launch: LaunchScreen, });

export default SwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: AppStack
});
```

In my LaunchScreen.js

```
const SimpleTabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      path: ""
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUp,
      path: "doctor"
    }
  },
);

<SimpleTabs screenProps={{rootNavigation : this.props.navigation  }}/>
```

But the problem is in my LaunchScreen Component there is a TabNavigator which contains my other two components Login.js and SignUp.js but the button in my Login.js doesn't navigate it to Feed.js.

When you click on the button this is performed.

```
signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
    console.log("AAAAAsSSS");
  };
```

My **LaunchScreen.js** contains a **TabNavigation** which lets you slide between two components ie. **Login.js** and **SignUp.js**.

Now when you click on the Login button which is in **Login.js** component it will authenticate the user and will **switch** the entire **LauchScreen.js** component with the **Feed.js** component.

I am a noob to react-native.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) `(npm install --save react-native-router-flux)`

just make one Navigator.js file and define each page you wanted to navigate.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import LaunchScreen from '../components/LaunchScreen.js';
import Feed from '../components/Feed.js';


const Navigator = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="lauchscreen" component={LaunchScreen} hideNavBar initial /> 
        <Scene key="feedscreen" type="reset" hideNavBar component={Feed} />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Navigator;
```

now in your App.js file add this:

```
import Navigator from './src/Navigator.js';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
    return (
          <Navigator />
    );
  }
}
```

now in your login.js when you click on login button write this:

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

  onLoginClick() {
    Actions.feedscreen();
  }
```

Thats it.. happy coding.

Comment: Phew I am sorry man I just spent hell of time to read react-navigation library and I think it suits what I want to do but I just don't know. it will be hectic to go through another library and figure out things.

Comment: actually this library uses reactNavigation, and make it more simple, and you dont have to study anything, i already mention everything that you are trying to accomplish. well but its your choice after all..

Comment: Thanks, Sagar I will try it out and let's see what happens as reactnavigation making things tougher for me.

Comment: let me no if you stuck anywhere?

Comment: @SagarChavada can we use this instead of react navigation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to `Feeds.js` then navigate as 
`this.props.navigation.navigate('App');`

not as

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');`

because your

```
export default SwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: AppStack // here is your stack of Main
});
```

refer [example](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow)

Comment: Thank you for trying brother but I have gone through the entire example given by them. Please try to understand my problem. @HungrySoul has the idea of my issue.

Comment: Do you have access to your `navigation` then also pass `key`.  Create objects of navigate using `NavigationAction` pass `key` and `routeName` and dispatch that navigate object

Comment: Can you please share more information like error you getting or code of Component where your trying to use NAVIGATION   props

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue few months ago. Thank god you have spent just 6 hours, i almost spent around 4 days in finding a solution for it.

Coming to the issue, Please note that in react-navigation you can either navigate to siblings or children classes.

So here, You have a swtichNavigator which contain 2 stack navigators (say stack 1 and stack 2), stack1 has feeds and stack2 has a tab navigator with login and signup.

Now you want to navigate from login.js to feeds.js(say file name is feeds.js). As mentioned already you can not navigate back to parent or grandparent. Then how to solve this issue?

In react native you have the privilege to pass params (screenprops) from parent to children. Using this, you need to store `this.props.navigation` of launchScreen into a variable and pass it to tab/login (check the tree structure). Now in the login.js use this variable to navigate.

You are simply passing the navigating privilege from parent to children.

Editing here:

```
<InnerTab screenProps={{rootNavigation : this.props.navigation  }} />
```

Here, InnerTab is the tab navigator.

```
export const InnerTab = TabNavigator({
login: {
    screen: login,
    },
},
signup: {
    screen: signup,
    },
},
```

},

in login class, use `const { navigate } = this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation;`
Now you can use variable `navigate`.

I know its little tricky to understand but i have tried and it works.

Comment: This seems promising, but now I am stuck with how to pass navigation params with TabNavigator which holds login and signup? Please help.

Comment: i have edited the answer. Please have a look and post me back if you face any difficulty.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation') I added this into render function.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you said.

Comment: can you please check by logging "this.props.screenProps". It should have a key "rootNavigation".

Answer (score 0):

Write your Navigator.js file as below,

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const SwitchNavigatorStack = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='{nameofscreen}' screenOptions={screenOptions}>
            <Stack.Screen name='{nameofscreen}' component={{nameofscreen}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='{nameofscreen}' component={{nameofscreen}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='{nameofscreen}' component={{nameofscreen}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='{nameofscreen}' component={{nameofscreen}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default SwitchNavigatorStack
```

Once, you are done with that change your App.js file to,

```
import SignedInStack from './navigation'
import React from 'react'

export default function App() {
  return <SwitchNavigatorStack/>
}
```

After this, you are done with setting your project for navigating. In all the components where you want to add navigation  feature make sure you use the `navigation.navigate()` (or) `navigation.push()` method. Also make sure you hook `navigation` constant by import `useNavigation` library. For example,

```
const Login = () => {
   const navigation = useNavigation()
   < Button title = 'Login' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('{nameofscreen}')} />
}
```

with this code snippet you can implement navigation between screens using `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/stack`